# Run-time error '6': Overflow after installing Visual Basic 5.0 application on Windows XP

Tags: overflow, windows-xp

I have installed an application using its installer in Windows 98/ME and everything is fine.

However when I tried to install the application in Windows XP or Windows 11, there is a message : `Run-time error '6': Overflow.`

I am a Visual Basic programmer and get information that the application was developed with Visual Basic 5.0 and Microsoft Access 97.

I tried to analyze whether Microsoft Access 97 databases caused the errors in Windows XP.  The expectation is I can install the application on Windows XP or Windows 11.

What cause the errors and how to handle it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Migrating to VB6 20-some years ago would have been a good move, there's still some support for that in current Windows versions.

Comment: It is possible that the application was developed with Visual Basic 6.0.  It can't be exactly determined because it was compiled.